# Widget ordering but how

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Categories>(
      future: _futureCategories,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Categories> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final name = snapshot.data?.data;
          return DefaultTabController(
            length: 1,
            child: Scaffold(
              body: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: name?.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text(
                    ' ${name?[index].name}',
                  );
                },
              ),
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('List User Example'),
                bottom: TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.lime,
                  tabs: [
                    Text(' ${name?[0].name}'.toUpperCase()),
                  ],
                  isScrollable: true,
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return NewsError(
            errorMessage: '${snapshot.hasError}',
          );
        }
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This code fetching categories from JSON and uses them on Tabcontroller. The problem is in this current code I cannot access index value.
I am newbie and trying to understand the widget system of Flutter. How can I use Tabcontroller to use int index value on TabController?

Comment: Where do you want to access the name i.e inside appBar or inside of itemBuilder

Comment: inside appBar i think

Comment: You cant access the index inside appBar because `ListView.builder(` only iterate the tab names. You can use another method to archive the same if you want to know please confirm is this the issue.

Comment: I have the get index and put here Text(' ${name?[index].name}'.toUpperCase()), otherwise I can not show all categories on TabBar. Ok the second way to use manuel index names like Text(' ${name?[0].name}'.toUpperCase()), but it is not handy because the category id s can change.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Text(' ${name?[index].name}',);
```

change

```
return Text(' ${snapshot.data.name}',);
```

Comment: there is no problem on here . I can get index but not in 

tabs: [
                    Text(' ${name?[0].name}'.toUpperCase()),